# Crear menú con pandas en python3

Tags: python, pandas

me gustaría crear un menú con la librería simple_term_menu en python3, la idea es coger cada fila de una tabla creada por Pandas y almacenada en una archivo ".csv" e introducir cada fila como una opción de selección distinta. Por ejemplo:

Tengo esta tabla:

```
     ALIAS    HOSTNAME       IP     SYST   USER   PASSWORD
0    cisc1     cisco1   1.1.1.1    Cisco  Sergio Sergio
1    cisc2     cisco2   2.2.2.2    Cisco  Luis   Luis
```

Me gustaría coger las columnas: alias, hostname, ip y syst de todas las filas y que cada fila se pueda seleccionar en el menú, el menú sería algo así:

```
> Cisc1 cisco1 1.1.1.1 Cisco
  Cisc2 cisco2 2.2.2.2 Cisco
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase `simple_term_menu.TerminalMenu` espera que se le proporciones algún iterable con cadenas para  las opciones a su inicializador. Por lo tanto, debes construir la cadena de cada entrada concatenando los valores de cada fila del DataFrame.

Tienes varias posibilidades, pero una simple es aplicar `str.join` sobre los datos de cada fila:

```
import io

import pandas as pd
from simple_term_menu import TerminalMenu


# Solo para emular un archivo .csv para poder reproducir el código fácilmente
csv = io.StringIO("""\
ALIAS,HOSTNAME,IP,SYST,USER,PASSWORD
0,cisc1,cisco1,1.1.1.1,Cisco,Sergio,Sergio
1,cisc2,cisco2,2.2.2.2,Cisco,Luis,Luis
""")


def menu(entries):
    terminal_menu = TerminalMenu(entries)
    return terminal_menu.show()

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
opciones = map(" ".join, df.iloc[:, :-2].to_numpy())
opcion = menu(opciones)

fila_elegida = df.iloc[opcion, :]
print(f"Seleccionada fila {opcion}:\n{fila_elegida}")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste método fallará si alguna columna no se de tipo `str`, en ese caso, otra opción es recurrir a [`pandas.DataFrame.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) y dejar que se encargue de formatear cada línea:

```
opciones = df.iloc[:, :-2].to_string(index=False, header=False,).splitlines()
```

Comment: Y en la variable csv introduzco lo que contiene el fichero o lo leo con csv_read? T puedo enseñar lo que tengo de momento abajo.

Comment: El fichero lo lees con `csv_read` pasando le la ruta que tenga, `import io` y la variable `csv` son solo para emular el fichero y que el ejemplo sea fácilmente reproducible para cualquier usuario, en tu código quita ambas líneas y haz `df = pd.read_csv("ruta/a/tu/archivo.csv")`

Comment: No hay errores pero al mostrar el menú no aparece texto, dejo abajo la última modificación

Comment: Hola, no uses nunca las respuestas para agregar código o actualizar la pregunta, usa el botón editar que hay debajo de la propia pregunta y añade el nuevo código a ella. El apartado de respuestas es solo para respuestas a la pregunta.

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema, ¿llegas a llamar en algún momento a `config()`?

Comment: Si, desde otro archivo

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y funciona en mi caso sin problemas, ¿Seguro que el separador del csv es ";"? De no serlo justifica que no aparezca ninguna opción.

Comment: Si, esto es lo que me dice la terminal:

Comment: File "/home/sergio/Escritorio/NETSYS/Configurar/conf_dispositives.py", line 38, in ping_list
    opcion = menu(opciones)
  File "/home/sergio/Escritorio/NETSYS/Configurar/conf_dispositives.py", line 33, in menu
    terminal_menu = TerminalMenu(entries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/simple_term_menu.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._menu_entries = tuple(menu_entries)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108422/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-user96431).